# How to ignore last occurrence of character?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a regular expression that looks like this:

```
/([A-z0-9]+\-)+/g
```

It matches the pattern `test-string-` out of `test-string-5RtA`. How can I ignore that last `-` character (but only the last one) out of that match. I tried using a positive lookahead but that doesn't seem to do anything. How can I modify my regular expression to exclude the last `-` character?

[Here](https://regexr.com/54d0v) is the link to see the regular expression in action.

Comment: It seems odd that you would want to match `"["`, `"\\"`, `"]"`, `"^"`, `"_"` and `"\`"`, the six ASCII characters that fall between `"Z"` and `"a"`. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for recognizing that error. I was trying to just get all capital and lower case letters. I should just specify the case-insensitive flag and change it to `A-Z`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lookahead should work fine for this purpose if you use it correctly. Try something like this:

```
^[A-z0-9-]+(?=-)
```

Because `+` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/13485806), it will match as many `-` characters as possible (except for the last one because of the Lookahead).

**[Demo](https://regexr.com/54d2f)**.

Note: I added `^` to make sure the match starts at the beginning of the string. You may remove it if your string might not start with an alphanumeric character and you still consider it as a valid match.

---

If you want to make sure that `-` always comes after one or more alphanumeric characters (i.e., no consecutive `-`), you may use something like this instead:

```
^(?:[A-z0-9]+-?)+(?=-)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/R8ShCM/1)**.

Comment: What do I do if I was to ignore two consecutive `-`?

Comment: @AlexLowe Updated the answer.

Comment: Alex, what do you mean by *ignore* two consecutive hyphens? Do you mean permit the string to end with two consecutive hyphens but not with one (or three or more consecutive) hyphen(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to match strings that contain the specified characters but do not end with a hyphen.

```
[A-z0-9+\-]+(?<!-)
```

[PCRE Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xRMF0V/1/)

There seems to be no need for a capture group.

`(?<!-)` is a *negative lookbehind*. After `[A-z0-9+\-]+` has matched  `"c-at-"` in the string `"c-at-*"`, for example, the regex's internal string pointer would be located between the second hyphen and the star. The negative lookbehind, which asserts that the previous character cannot be a hyphen, would then fail. The regex engine would then backtrack one character (to between `"t"` and `"-"`), at which point the negative lookbehind would be satisfied, resulting in `"c-at"` being matched.